# Vuejs Hide a div when v-model is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a select dropdown like this.

```html
<select v-model="selectedInjection">
    <option v-for="(match,i) in haufigkeitMatches"
        :key="i"
        :value="match.value" >{{ match.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

I am rendering the value in this way

```html
<td v-if="selectedInjection">{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}</td>
```

The value of the `{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}` changes when the select value changes and it's working fine. But when I do not select any value, the `{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}` is showing the old selected value unless I select a new value. 
How can I hid the `{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}` when the select value is empty?

Here is the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ey3scra0/

Comment: You can try the condition on your v-if condition : v-if="selectedInjection.length>0".

Comment: I assume that options are getting populated from an API. In that case, check haufigkeitMatches.length > 0.
Other wise check initial value of selectedInjection. Eg. if initial value of selectedInjection is ''. Check selectedInjection !== ''

Comment: Be wary of using the index in a loop for the key. Vue will lose track if you do this and could result in bugs..

Comment: v-if="selectedInjection.length>0" gives me error ```Cannot read property 'length' of null```I have edited my question and attached a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) in your div:

```
<div class="hideResult" v-show="showSelectedInjection && selectedProduct != ''">
   {{Math.round(selectedInjection)}}
</div>
```

Then add @change on second select:

```
<select v-model="selectedInjection" @change="setShowSelectedInjection">
```

Also you need to add extra field `showSelectedInjection` with method `setShowSelectedInjection` and set `showSelectedInjection` in `setSelectsToDefault`:

```
data:{
showSelectedInjection: false,

(...)

methods:{
            setSelectsToDefault(){
                this.selectedIeProKg = 0;
                this.selectedPreisProIE = 0;
                this.showSelectedInjection = this.haufigkeitMatches.map(h => h.value).includes(this.selectedInjection);
            },
            setShowSelectedInjection(){
                this.showSelectedInjection = true;
            }
```

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mo3vng6/)

Comment: Hi, ```v-show="selectedInjection > 0"``` doesn't help. You can check in the jsfiddle in my question. If i set ```this.selectedInjection = 0```, then it resets the ```v-model="selectedInjection"``` which I should not.  When I do first select and then second select, then it outputs a value. When I reset the first select to empty option, then second second select does go to empty automatically. But ```{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}}``` is staying around.

Comment: Updated answer and JSFiddle link - now your selectedInjection model is not resetted. I have added extra field showSelectedInjection .

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working like 90%, when I set the first select and second select, it gives a value, then immediately when I set the first select to empty option, then the second select is also getting empty, which is good But still the value is hanging around.

Comment: Updated answer and JSFiddle link - I have added extra condition in `v-show` for that edge case: `v-show="showSelectedInjection && selectedProduct != ''"`. I hope it works 100% now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much it hits your problem because you haven't provided an example of how the data in your application changes. If a variable depends on another variable, you must observe it and control that change. Just like me here, I follow a variable, check if it is empty and then reset the second variable. If this is still not the case, enter more data, a larger piece of code, then I will also adjust the answer.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    selectedInjection: null,
    haufigkeitMatches: []
  },
  computed: {
    round() {
      return Math.round(this.selectedInjection);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    haufigkeitMatches(val) {
      if (!val.length) {
        this.selectedInjection = null;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.haufigkeitMatches.push({
        name: 'Fus',
        value: 1.1
      }, {
        name: 'Ro',
        value: 2.2
      }, {
        name: 'Dah',
        value: 3.3
      })
    },
    del() {
      this.haufigkeitMatches = [];
    }
  }

}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedInjection">
    <option v-for="(match,i) in haufigkeitMatches" :key="i" :value="match.value">{{ match.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <div v-show="selectedInjection">{{round}}</div>
  <div>DIV is {{selectedInjection ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}}</div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
  <button @click="del">Del</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide more code, and it's best to insert a code snippet to make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have edited my question and I have attached jsfiddle in it

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. It is clearing the old value everytime. Please try this.

```
<div id="app">
                  <select v-model="selectedProduct" @change="setSelectsToDefault">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option v-for="(level1,index) in products"
                            :key="index"
                            :value="level1">{{level1.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <select v-model="selectedInjection">
                    <option v-for="(match,i) in haufigkeitMatches"
                            :key="i"
                            :value="match.value" >{{ match.name }}</option>
                </select>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                  <td class="table-result-body-ipJahr"><div class="hideResult" v-if="selectedInjection> 0">{{Math.round(selectedInjection)}}</div></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
</div>


    "use strict";

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selectedPreisProIE: [],
            selectedIeProKg: [],
            selectedGewicht: [],
            selectedInjection: '',
            selectedProduct: null,
            dataJson: [],
            products: [{
                name: "ivi",
                Hint: "45-60 IE/kg alle 5 Tage\n60 IE 1x/Woche\n30-40 IE 2 x/Woche",
                frequency: [1, 2, 8]
            }, {
                name: "ynovi",
                Hint: "40-50 IE/kg\n2x/Woche im Abstand\nvon 3-4 Tagen",
                frequency: [2, 6, 7]
            }, {
                name: "octa",
                Hint: "50 (25-65) IE/kg\nalle 3-5 Tage",
                frequency: [6, 7, 8]
            }, {
                name: "eroct",
                Hint: "50 IE/kg \nalle 4 Tage",
                frequency: [7]
            }, {
                name: "ltry",
                Hint: "20-40 I.E./kg\n2-3x/Woche",
                frequency: [2, 3]
            }, {
                name: "ate",
                Hint: "20-40 I.E./kg\nAlle 2-3 Tage",
                frequency: [5, 6]
            }, {
                name: "Facto A",
                Hint: "20-40 I.E./kg\nAlle 2-3 Tage",
                frequency: [5, 6]
            }, {
                name: "Eight",
                Hint: "40-60 I.E./kg \nJeden 3.Tag oder\n2x/Woche",
                frequency: [2, 3, 5, 6]
            }, {
                name: "iq_Vima",
                Hint: "20-40 I.E./kg\nAlle 2-3 Tage",
                frequency: [5, 6]
            }, {
                name: "Afla",
                Hint: "20-50 I.E./kg\n2-3x/Woche",
                frequency: [2, 3]
            }, {
                name: "Pma",
                Hint: "20-40 I.E./kg\nAlle 2-3 Tage",
                frequency: [5, 6]
            }, {
                name: "others",
                Hint: "Individuell",
                frequency: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            }],
            haufigkeit: [{
                name: "1x / Woche",
                id: 1,
                value: 52.1428571429
            }, {
                name: "2x / Woche",
                value: 104.2857142857143,
                id: 2
            }, {
                name: "3x / Woche",
                value: 156.4285714285714,
                id: 3
            }, {
                name: "alle 1 Tage",
                value: 365,
                id: 4
            }, {
                name: "alle 2 Tage",
                value: 182.5,
                id: 5
            }, {
                name: "alle 3 Tage",
                value: 121.6666666666667,
                id: 6
            }, {
                name: "alle 4 Tage",
                value: 91.25,
                id: 7
            }, {
                name: "alle 5 Tage",
                value: 73,
                id: 8
            }]
        },
        computed: {
            haufigkeitMatches: function haufigkeitMatches() {
                var _this = this;

                if (this.selectedProduct) {
                    return this.haufigkeit.filter(function (x) {
                        return _this.selectedProduct.frequency.includes(x.id);
                    });
                }
            },
        },
        methods:{
            setSelectsToDefault(){
                this.selectedIeProKg = 0;
                this.selectedPreisProIE = 0;
                this.selectedGewicht = 0;
                this.selectedInjection='';
            }
            }
    });
```